# Lost data in Tar

Tags: tar

I had a tar file which was of size 3.5gb which held all my programming code.
I was working with git trying to learn the repositories, so I created this file as a backup, so I could work my code directory and if anything were to go wrong I could just delete and extract it.

I did this a few times and it worked great, then I restarted and remounted my drive and the tar file was not 10kb instead of 3,5gb and all its contents were gone.

What could have happened?

Comment: what was the tar command that you used?

Comment: to extract?

tar -xf name.tar

Comment: I've stumbled upon an article written quite recently: http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2Fblogs%2Flinux%2F77271%2F&sl=ru&tl=en&swap=1 . Should be useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What filesystem do you use? It can be a FS failure. Try `fsck` on that partition.

And learn how to press the "accept answer" button, or you'll never get any responces.

Comment: data was lost on a ext3

Comment: As far as i know, there are no recovery options for ext* filesystems :( `fsck` and backups is the only thing to try.